# How to get rid of blank page after title+ get the page number for chapter 2+ even on left and odd on right pages numbers

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr

I need 3 events happening together:

1. get rid of blank page after title
2. get the page number for chapter 2 in header with `fancyhdr`
3. even on left and odd on right pages numbers for all the pages after title in header

---

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperheight=9.8125in,paperwidth=8in, left=.5in, 
right=.5in,top=.75in,bottom=.4375in }
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[EL,OR]{\textbf 
{\thepage}}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pag}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\titlefontarash}{\usefont{OT1}{pag}{b}{n}\fontsize{25} 
{\baselineskip} \selectfont}
\newcommand{\basefontarash}{\usefont{OT1}{pag}{b}{n}\fontsize{18} 
{\baselineskip} \selectfont}
\title{\titlefontarash  Helping each other}
\author{\basefontarash Good boy}
\maketitle
\frontmatter
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\basefontarash To good...
\basefontarash To those good..
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\tableofcontents
\newgeometry{ left=2.75in, right=.5in }
\mainmatter
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ \fancyhf{}\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\textbf 
{\thepage}\hspace*{2.25in}}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Introducing the fish}
\section{fox}
referring to \citet{Fish(1979)}.
A \textbf{fish}  (or \textbf{cat}) jungle sky.
\section{river}
\chapter{Introduction2}
\section{Introducing the fish2}
\section{fox2}
\newgeometry{ left=.5in, right=.5in}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\textbf 
{\thepage}}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[Fish(1979)]{Fish(1979)} Fish, Y(1979) \textit{orange HHH} New York: 
hot.  
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several issues resulting in your problems:

1. In class `book` command `\maketitle` uses an `\cleardoublepage` at the end. To get rid of that build a group with `\maketitle` and `\frontmatter` and deactivate `\clearpage` inside this group ...

   ```
   { % <===================================================================
   \maketitle
   \let\cleardoublepage\relax

   \frontmatter
   } % <===================================================================
   ```
2. Your page geometry for your chapters is very strange. To show that effect simply add option `showframe` for package `geometry` to your code and compile. Then you see the strange result of your `\geometry` commands. In the following mwe I simply commented this unusual `geometry` settings ...
3. I moved command `\newcommand{\titlefontarash}` and command `\newcommand{\basefontarash}` into the preamble ...
4. I commented/deleted your redefinition of style `plain`, its not needed with unchanged page geometry  ...

Please see the following complete MWE

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % <====================================
\geometry{%
  paperheight=9.8125in,
  paperwidth=8in, 
  left=.5in, right=.5in,top=.75in,bottom=.4375in 
}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{} 
  \fancyhead[EL,OR]{\textbf {\thepage}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pag}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}

\newcommand{\titlefontarash}{% 
  \usefont{OT1}{pag}{b}{n}%
  \fontsize{25}{\baselineskip}%
  \selectfont%
}
\newcommand{\basefontarash}{%
  \usefont{OT1}{pag}{b}{n}%
  \fontsize{18}{\baselineskip}%
  \selectfont%
}


\begin{document}

\title{\titlefontarash  Helping each other}
\author{\basefontarash Good boy}
{ % <===================================================================
\maketitle
\let\clearpage\relax

\frontmatter
} % <===================================================================
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
  \basefontarash To good...
  \basefontarash To those good..
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}

\tableofcontents

%\newgeometry{ left=2.75in, right=.5in } % <======================= ?????
\mainmatter
%\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  %\fancyhf{}
  %\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\textbf {\thepage}\hspace*{2.25in}} % <========== ?????
  %\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%}
\pagestyle{plain}

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Introducing the fish}
\section{fox}
referring to \citet{Fish(1979)}.
A \textbf{fish}  (or \textbf{cat}) jungle sky.
\section{river}

\chapter{Introduction2}
\section{Introducing the fish2}
\section{fox2}
%\newgeometry{ left=.5in, right=.5in}
%\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\textbf 
%{\thepage}}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
%\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[Fish(1979)]{Fish(1979)} Fish, Y(1979) \textit{orange HHH} New York: 
hot.  
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting page]

Now -- if that solution does not help you -- please ask a new question and explain exactly in this new question, what you want to get as a layout for your chapter 1 etc. To be honest I could not guess what you want from your given code ...

With your activated geometry you get the following chapter 1, where the pagenumber can not be placed:

[image: strange geometry result]

## UPDATED Answer:

After your explanation in comments see the following changed code:

```
\newgeometry{ left=2.75in, right=.5in } % <======================= ?????
\mainmatter
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[OR]{\textbf {\thepage}\hspace*{2.25in}} % <================
  \fancyhead[EL]{\textbf {\hspace*{2.25in}\thepage}} % <================
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\pagestyle{plain}
```

Because you changed the left margin from `.5in` to `2.75in` you need to add a `\hspace*{2.25in}` to the new definition for the header. B careful, for the odd and even header you need to add `\hspace` different!

So with the following code

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % <====================================
\geometry{%
  paperheight=9.8125in,
  paperwidth=8in, 
  left=.5in, right=.5in,top=.75in,bottom=.4375in 
}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{} 
  \fancyhead[EL,OR]{\textbf {\thepage}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pag}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}

\newcommand{\titlefontarash}{% 
  \usefont{OT1}{pag}{b}{n}%
  \fontsize{25}{\baselineskip}%
  \selectfont%
}
\newcommand{\basefontarash}{%
  \usefont{OT1}{pag}{b}{n}%
  \fontsize{18}{\baselineskip}%
  \selectfont%
}


\begin{document}

\title{\titlefontarash  Helping each other}
\author{\basefontarash Good boy}
{ % <===================================================================
\maketitle
\let\clearpage\relax

\frontmatter
} % <===================================================================
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
  \basefontarash To good...
  \basefontarash To those good..
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}

\tableofcontents

\newgeometry{ left=2.75in, right=.5in } % <======================= ?????
\mainmatter
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[OR]{\textbf {\thepage}\hspace*{2.25in}} % <================
  \fancyhead[EL]{\textbf {\hspace*{2.25in}\thepage}} % <================
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Introducing the fish}
\section{fox}
referring to \citet{Fish(1979)}.
A \textbf{fish}  (or \textbf{cat}) jungle sky.
\section{river}
\Blinddocument

\chapter{Introduction2}
\section{Introducing the fish2}
\section{fox2}
\newgeometry{ left=.5in, right=.5in}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\textbf 
{\thepage}}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[Fish(1979)]{Fish(1979)} Fish, Y(1979) \textit{orange HHH} New York: 
hot.  
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: chapter 1]

and

[image: chapter 2]

Comment: I want to use wide right margins on the body of the book. I can not have narrow margins. That is why I used new geometry.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the empty page:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperheight=9.8125in,paperwidth=8in, left=.5in, 
right=.5in,top=.75in,bottom=.4375in }
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[EL,OR]{\textbf 
{\thepage}}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pag}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\titlefontarash}{\usefont{OT1}{pag}{b}{n}\fontsize{25} 
{\baselineskip} \selectfont}
\newcommand{\basefontarash}{\usefont{OT1}{pag}{b}{n}\fontsize{18} 
{\baselineskip} \selectfont}
\title{\titlefontarash  Helping each other}
\author{\basefontarash Good boy}
{
\maketitle
\let\newpage\relax
\frontmatter
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\basefontarash To good...
\basefontarash To those good..
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
}
\tableofcontents
\newgeometry{ left=2.75in, right=.5in }
\mainmatter
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ \fancyhf{}\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\textbf 
{\thepage}\hspace*{2.25in}}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Introducing the fish}
\section{fox}
referring to \citet{Fish(1979)}.
A \textbf{fish}  (or \textbf{cat}) jungle sky.
\section{river}
\chapter{Introduction2}
\section{Introducing the fish2}
\section{fox2}
\newgeometry{ left=.5in, right=.5in}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\textbf 
{\thepage}}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[Fish(1979)]{Fish(1979)} Fish, Y(1979) \textit{orange HHH} New York: 
hot.  
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: hi Vadu would u explain how u removed the blank?

Comment: @ArashRashidi I temporarily disabled `\newpage` to do nothing

Comment: thanks! yes do u know how to get page number for chapter2?

Comment: @ArashRashidi I think all the page numbers are already there, but they are not visible because of the geometry of the page